# Source in Caption: how to change it

Tags: tumblr, customization

I'm having a little trouble customizing my Tumblr theme (I'm currently using 'The Minimalist Theme' by Pixel Union).

When I reblog a picture, I usually like to write some text below the image. In this theme I'm using, the source of the reblogged content appears below the text, like this:

```
[********Image*******]
[text]
(Source:_______).
```

I don't want to remove the credits, I just want to replace it, and put it under the image, before the text, like this.

```
[********Image*******]
(Source:_______)
[text].
```

But it seems that the "source element" is in the {Caption}.

My theme does not have a {block:RebloggedFrom} or something.

Do you have any thoughts?